# What is the most straightforward way to create compound views in IOS?

Tags: ios

The goal here is to be able to create complex views using the `XIB`, link them to a view class, and be able to instantiate them simply by using `CompoundView()`. Right now I'm creating the `.xib` file using `XIB`, and then using this code in the `CompoundView's` inititializers to add it:

```
let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CompoundView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView
view.frame=self.bounds
self.addSubview(view)
```

However, this will always result in a container containing a container -- a single view subclass (`CompoundView.swift`) that has a single child view (the superview of the `CompoundView.xib` file). I'm looking for a way to create a compound view without the redundancy, that's at least as straightforward as what I'm doing now.

In android you can create an `xml` layout that is surrounded by a `<merge>` tag, and when that layout is inflated into an object and added to a view, that view will adopt all of that `<merge>` tag's children, but not the `<merge>` tag itself, essentially "removing the middle-man".

Is there a way of doing this in ios, or will that "middle-man" always be there without programmatic manipulation?

Comment: Found a solution for this?